# Contour Integration Using Substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

evaluate the integral
$$I = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1+x^2} $$
using substitution $x=\cos(\theta)$ to show
$$I=-\pi+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(1+cos^2(\theta))^{-1}d\theta$$
Then use $z=e^{i\theta}$ to write
$$I = -\pi+\int g(z)dz$$
And hence evaluate I using the residue theorem.

I hope someone can help, i don't even know where to start. I subbed in $x=\cos(\theta)$, and i can't see how you change the limits from -1 & 1 to -pi & pi

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: What is $\theta$ when $x=\cos(\theta)=\pm 1$?

Comment: i got when x=+1 theta=0 and when x=-1 theta=pi

Comment: thanks mike van der naald for editing! Any chance you know the solution to the first show that part? I've managed to do the rest